# PowerShell SAST / OWASP 10

Tags: powershell, security, sonarqube, fortify, sast

I am currently developing a PowerShell script with 10k lines of code connecting to a SQL DB.
While it is considered a best practice to use plug-ins in the IDE for example for Java or C# to scan the code (Resharper/ Fortify or Sonarcube plugin) and during the build process, perform a SAST analysis, I cannot find any tool suited for PowerShell code except the PSScriptAnalyzer which is good for bad smells but not so much considered a SAST tool.

Is such a tool currently simply not available for PowerShell or do you know any useful tools?

KR
Chris

Comment: "but not so much considered a SAST tool." - by whom? PSSA is meant to analyze and optimize for correctness - which is exactly the first property you'd want from a SAST tool :)

Comment: Yeah, it's for sure a static code scanner but to my knowledge it does not really scan security issues / OWASP like fortify would do. A few rules related to security are there like if you name a string $Credential it would be recognized but the rules are rather on a basic level...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NIST keeps a regularly updated list of SAST tool examples (not recommendations) [here](https://www.nist.gov/itl/ssd/software-quality-group/source-code-security-analyzers). As of August 20, 2021, the only tool that lists Powershell as a supported language is Atlassian's [Static Reviewer](https://securityreviewer.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/196633/Static+Reviewer+-+Code+Inspection):

> Provides security checks in compliance with OWASP, CWE, CVE, CVSS, MISRA, CERT. Available as a module for Software Composition Analysis (SCA) to find vulnerabilities in open source and third party libraries

Personally, I just use the `PSScriptAnalyzer` module with Microsoft's [InjectionHunter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-injection-hunter-security-auditing-for-powershell-scripts/) ruleset. These days, you can add them to VSCode's powershell plugin rules.